# how to sort data using columns in other tables in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table `course` with columns: `id`, `title`, `desc` and also have a table `curriculum` with columns: `id`, `title_curriculum`, `trigger_lecture` and `course_id`. I want to sort `course` table value using column `trigger_lecture` in the `curriculum` table, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Simple join:

```
select course.*
from course
join curriculum on curriculum.course_id = course.id
order by trigger_lecture
;
```

[MySQl join example](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5a7316a983125c7f4c1927763aa5ce63&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)